# APEX: Date Picker in Tabular Form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have region Tabular Form "Employees" like this

```
Employee|Start_date | End_date  |
John A  |2015-10-20 | 2015-10-25|
John C  |2016-03-15 | 2016-03-25|
```

Start_date - Date Picker

End_date - Date Picker

I want disable **previous** and **next** in both data picker.

So if I will click Start_date on second employee I would like change date from 2016-03-01 to 2016-03-31

Comment: I don't understand. What is "previous" and "next" in the datepicker? How does that relate to you wanting to automatically change the date? Why does the date have to change in that way? I'm really missing context and details here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the template provide by ApEx, you can achieve this with the below code.

`<style>
    .ui-datepicker-next, .ui-datepicker-prev {
    display : none;
    }
</style>`

**NOTE:** This code may not work if you have customized template.

Answer (score 0):

you need to setup the datepicker minumum date and maximum date propeties which are under settings group of date picker

-0d means sysdate

-1w limits to 1 week before the sysdate

+1w limits to 1 week late of the sysdate

help of this setting describes as below

The date value can be an absolute value in 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS' or 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI' format or a relative value with respect to today's date, such as +7d, or a dynamic value using substitution syntax, providing the substitution returns the correct date format or relative value.

Relative date values include:

y
+ / - years from today's date

m
+ / - months from today's date

w
+ / - weeks from today's date

d
+ / - days from today's date